# how do I add to a JSON field in Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, postgresql, django-models, django-views

AIM --- I am using Django to make a mock trading website for a project. I am running into problems trying to keep track of stocks a person owns. The problem is if someone buys 4 TSLA stocks and then 4 again it should be treated as 8 stocks of TSLA out of which they can sell 7 if they want. (BTW, I am using postgresql)

Problem --- Turns out this is very difficult to do, I couldn't find anything that would help me keep track of the stocks a person owns. so, I read and read and finally turned to JSON fields. but, I am running into an issue there are well when I do

```
u.stocks_owned = {f"{ticker}" : f"{stocks_bought_here}"}
u.save()
```

it works, it adds a key-value pair with the ticker and a number, but I don't know how to create a new row using this, or if someone already owns some stock of a company then how do I add to that??

Conclusion --- I don't need to to write code for me, just point me in the right direction I will figure it out myself!

User Model -

```
class User_Info(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, related_name='info', on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank = True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank = True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    balance = models.FloatField(null = True)
    virtual_money_bought = models.BigIntegerField(null=True)
    stocks_owned = models.JSONField(null=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

the view I am using --

```
if  new_balance >= 0 and balance_pre_trade >= latestPrice * stocks_bought_here :
                Trade.objects.create(
                    ticker = ticker, 
                    stocks_bought = stocks_bought_here, 
                    action = "Bought",
                    trader = user.info,
                    price_trade_at = latestPrice,
                    company_name = companyName,
                    balance_of_trader_after_purchase= new_balance
                )
                u = User_Info.objects.get(user = user)
                u.balance = new_balance
                u.stocks_owned = {f"{ticker}" : f"{stocks_bought_here}"}
                u.save()
                messages.success(request, f"You bought {stocks_bought_here} from {companyName} at a price of {latestPrice} ")
                return redirect ("user")
            else:
                messages.error(request, "You dont have enough money in your account")
```

Comment: A new row of which model? Seeing your existing models would be helpful, otherwise we can only speculate. JSON fields do not magically create parent-child relations. You must fetch the existing field, modify/add to it, then write it back. In your case I would create a separate `Stock` model with a foreign key to `User`.

Comment: I will put the model in the question! so what you are saying is I should create a sotck_owned model that would keep track of all the stocks owned by a person, I will look into that, might be something worth exploring :)

Comment: Correct. Also try to follow PEP-8 when naming classes (i.e. use `UserInfo` instead of `User_Info`) as most Python developers are used to that convention.

Comment: okay, dude, I will keep that in mind, I am new to this so I am still learning, so thank you for the advice!